# BLE scan function does not work properly in ionic v4 app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ionic4

I created a small app with **ionic framework v4**.

I installed the **cordova-plugin-ble-central** and used the **scan()** function to scan all the devices but it does not find all devices. For example, I am trying to scan a Samsung Galaxy S6 but it cannot be found.

Mine mobile is **Samsung Galaxy S8**.

My code in **home.page.ts**:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { BLE } from "@ionic-native/ble/ngx";
import { AlertController, ToastController } from "@ionic/angular";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "home.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["home.page.scss"]
})
export class HomePage {
  devices: any[] = [];
  statusMessage: string;

  constructor(
    private ble: BLE,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private toastCtrl: ToastController,
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) {
    this.checkBluetooth();
  }

  checkBluetooth() {
    this.ble.isEnabled().then(
      success => {
        this.showToast("Bluetooth is enabled");
      },
      error => {
        this.showError("Bluetooth is *not* enabled");
      }
    );
  }

  enableBluetooth() {
    this.ble.enable().then(
      success => {
        this.showToast("Bluetooth is enabled");
      },
      error => {
        this.showError("The user did *not* enable Bluetooth");
      }
    );
  }

  listDevices() {
    this.setStatus("Scanning for bluetooth LE devices");
    this.devices = [];

    this.ble
      .scan([], 5)
      .subscribe(
        device => this.onDeviceDiscovered(device),
        error => this.showError("No devices because " + error)
      );
    setTimeout(this.setStatus.bind(this), 5000, "Scan complete");
  }

  onDeviceDiscovered(device) {
    this.showToast("Discovered " + JSON.stringify(device, null, 2));
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.devices.push(device);
    });
  }

  setStatus(message) {
    this.showToast(message);
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.statusMessage = message;
    });
  }

  async showError(error) {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: "Error",
      subHeader: error,
      buttons: ["OK"]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }

  async showToast(msj) {
    const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: msj,
      duration: 1000
    });
    await toast.present();
  }
}

interface pairedlist {
  class: number;
  id: string;
  address: string;
  name: string;
}
```

How can scan work correctly to find all devices? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe its because you use BLE  and not all phone are using ble ?

Comment: @Sam how can I know if my phone uses BLE? And in case I want to scan other devices that do not use BLE, can you recommend me a plugin for scanning also those devices?

Comment: Yes this plugin allow you to connect other device :  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial ,  the doc say you can connect with Arduino. but  you can connect to other devices too

Comment: @Sam thank you so much. Is it possible to use both plugins for my ionic app?

Comment: I don't know if you can use the both at same time. in the same app I think its possible not at the same time.

Comment: @Sam thank you so much for the help. it works and you can use both plugins at the same time.